# Printer Emulators, PDF Writers and so on

Tags: pdf, printing, gdi, emulation

I will soon be working on 'Print' and 'Print Preview' features of a product I am working on.  I do not own a printer nor do I have any intention of buying one. I am looking for any free software which I can use to test my printing code.

What are the best free options I can use to emulate a printer? I am using GDI+ on Windows but platform independent options such as PDF writers are more than welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know a quite good pdf printer, used for many years: [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) and it's free :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use at least 1 PDF printer and if you have a recent MS Office installed you probably already have an XPS printer as well. Otherwise, look for an XPS package at Microsoft.

Anyway, test with more than one.

Answer (score 2):

[PDF Creator](http://www.pdfforge.org/) is nice (and also open source)
.

It creates a virtual printer, and prints PDFs via Ghostscript.

Comment: I don't recommend this due to bundled crapware, check wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFCreator

Comment: That's unfortunately true - it didn't use to, but it has since some time in 2009.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a list of best PDF Writers/Creater and most of them are FREE at http://www.wwwlabz.com/list-of-best-pdf-creatorswriters-mostly-free-alternative-to-adobe-pdf-writer